# It is possible in UWP to set package.manifest property from C# code?

Tags: c#, uwp

It is possible in UWP to set package. manifest property from C# code?

I want to set all Assets images from C# code depending on some condition like if(MA) - Assets Type 1 if(OC) - Assets Type 2

```
<Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="MangoAppsUWP.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="MangoApps"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="MangoApps"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png"  BackgroundColor="#ffffff" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
          <uap:AppService Name="MangoAppsUWPWin32ExtensionService" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap5:Extension
              Category="windows.startupTask"
              Executable="MangoAppsUWP.exe"
              EntryPoint="MangoAppsUWP.App">
          <uap5:StartupTask
              TaskId="MangoAppsUWPStartUpId"
              Enabled="true"
              DisplayName="MangoApps" />
        </uap5:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible in UWP to set [package.manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest) property from C# code?

Currently, there is no such way that could edit [`package.manifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest) programmatically at run time.

> The package manifest is an XML document that contains the info the system needs to deploy, display, or update a Windows app. This info includes package identity, package dependencies, required capabilities, visual elements, and extensibility points.

Manifest is used to deploy app and set the app's permissions to the system. So it cannot change values at runtime.

Comment: What are `MA` and `OC` in your example above? Windows lets you have multiple versions of assets based on different attributes (language, accessibility, scale-factor, etc.) that might work for you.